# Making keyboard keys edge to edge

Tags: android-softkeyboard

Please help me to remove any distance "gap" between the keys in a row of a custom keyboard. I tried to set android:horizontalGap="0%p for no avail.
Sorry I could not post an image with less than 10 reputation, so I tried to link it here [here](http://s28.postimg.org/pd61yh7zh/Untitled.jpg)
Thank you

```
<Keyboard
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:keyHeight="60dp">
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
    <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2" android:horizontalGap="0%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3" android:horizontalGap="0%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4" android:horizontalGap="0%"/>
    <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5" android:horizontalGap="0%"/>
    <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6" android:horizontalGap="0%"/>
    <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7" android:horizontalGap="0%"/>
    <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8" android:horizontalGap="0%"/>
    <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9" android:horizontalGap="0%"/>
    <Key android:codes="58" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
</Row>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set it to negative,

```
android:horizontalGap="-1%p"
android:verticalGap="-1%p"
```

and I can see keys are now closer. Do some hit and trial and you should be good to go.